# XS typemap for intptr_t

Tags: perl, intptr, xs

I'm trying to return an intptr_t type from some XS code:

```
intptr_t
my_func( self )
        myObjPtr self
    CODE:
        RETVAL = (intptr_t) self;
    OUTPUT:
        RETVAL
```

My typemap doesn't have anything about `intptr_t`, so of course `dmake` fails with `Could not find a typemap for C type 'intptr_t'.` I'm not sure if Perl even works with integers as big as `intptr_t` can be. If there's no good way to return this to Perl as a number, I'll just stringify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IV`, Perl's signed integer format, is guaranteed to be large enough to hold a pointer. `intptr_t` is C's version of what Perl has had for a long time. (In fact, a ref is just a pointer stored in a scalar's IV slot with a flag indicating it's a reference.)

But you don't want to cast directly to an `IV` as that can result in a spurious warning. As Sinan Ünür points out, use `PTR2IV` instead.

```
IV
my_func()
        myObjPtr self
    CODE:
        self = ...;
        RETVAL = PTR2IV(self);
    OUTPUT:
        RETVAL
```

`INT2PTR(myObjPtr, iv)` does the inverse operation.

Comment: Hum, but you probably want something blessed so you can free your object. Sorry, too tired to dig up how to do that exactly.

Answer (score 3):

[This thread](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2012/11/msg195325.html) suggests:

> The existing mechanism which does work everywhere are the macros `INT2PTR` and `PTR2IV` (in `perl.h`)

From [perldoc perlguts](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html#Pointer-To-Integer-and-Integer-To-Pointer):

> Because pointer size does not necessarily equal integer size, use the follow macros to do it right.
>
> ```
> PTR2UV(pointer)
> PTR2IV(pointer)
> PTR2NV(pointer)
> INT2PTR(pointertotype, integer)
> ```